# 4-cliques of pythagorean triples graph and its connectivity

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-number-theory

Let natural numbers $a, b > 2$ be adjacent if $|a^2 - b^2|$ is a square number. One can find a 3-clique.
For example 153, 185, 697. The questions are: does there exist a 4-clique? Is this graph connected?

Comment: 1st question is a duplicate: mathoverflow.net/questions/374394

Comment: @Yaakov, that question asks for numbers whose pairwise differences are squares, this one asks for *squares* whose pairwise differences are squares, no?

Comment: @Gerry, take their difference with the minimal number. They are squares, as well as their differences are such. (Thus, an example there provides a 3-clique.)

Comment: @Ilya, right you are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems that here is a proof that the graph is connected

Let $C$ be a component.

1. $C$  contains an even number, as an odd number $2k+1$ is adjacent to $2k(k+1)$.
2. $C$ contains a number divisible by $6$: if $2k\in C$ with $3\nmid k$, then $k^2-1\in C$ as well.
3. If $3k\in C$ and $p$ is a prime, then $3kp\in C$. Induction on $p$. The base cases $p=2,3$ follow from adjacencies $3k-5k-13k-12k-15k-17k-8k-10k-6k$ and $\dots-15k-9k$.  For the step, use the hypothesis to see that $C$ contains $3k(p^2-1)$, then $6kp$, and then $3kp$ by the base case.
4. The graph is connected. Indeed, any two components contain some numbers $3k$ and $3n$, and then both contain $3kn$.

Comment: Also we can observe that for the largest prime divisor $p = 2k + 1$ of $ap$ going to $2ak(k + 1)$ reduces the number of largest prime divisors (or the largest divisor itself), thus any number is connected to a power of $2$. All powers of $2$ are connected since $4k - 5k - 13k - 12k - 15k - 17k - 8k$.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, it seems to be a bit easier version of the same argument.